# Why disable Postgres Autovacuum?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, autovacuum

I've got a task to work with a 9.6 Postgres DB, and for some reason Autovacuum is disabled.

The database was extremely slow, and after a manual `VACUUM` it could breathe again.

The point is, why disable Autovaccum? Is there any practical scenario for a small database to have Autovaccum disabled?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to disable it. Whoever did that, did no have a clue on how to properly manage a Postgres database

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what if you have a db with high load half of the day and almost no use the other half? Wouldn't it be a good idea disable autovacuum and schedule a manual vacuum?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no good reason to keep autovacuum disabled in a production database, and you will run into problems if you do that.

It may make sense to disable autovacuum during exceptional operations, where you run a manual vacuum anyway and don't want your performance sapped by a background job, but more often than not such trickery is a premature optimization.

I would run `VACUUM (FULL)` on the database, followed by `VACUUM (ANALYZE)`. That shoud take care of any damage done.

Then enable autovacuum.